# json_encode for asp

Tags: php, jquery, json, asp-classic

I need to convert a json return from php to asp classic. How can I do that?

In index.php

```
<script>
function (){
    $.ajax({
       url: ajax.php,
       dataType: "json",
       data: {
       ROWID : rowid
       },
       success: function(data){
         alert(data[0]);
       }                    
       });
}
</script>
```

In ajax.php

```
echo json_encode(array(
    "TRUE"
));
return;
```

I will be getting a java alert messege 'TRUE'

what shall be in asp?

```
  Response.Write json_encode(array(
        "TRUE"
    ));
```

doesn't work. can't find a full solutuion to it. any ideas how shall I do it in asp classic?

Comment: There's no JSON functions in ASP-Classic. You'll have to write your own parser (if you insist on using them).

Comment: Try this: http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AXE](http://zend.lojcomm.com.br/goodies/asp-xtreme-evolution/) (ASP Xtreme Evolution) has some JSON libraries that might get you what you need.

See examples [here](http://zend.lojcomm.com.br/entries/classic-asp-json-revisited/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to convert to json with http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage JSON like PHP does, with .NET, you have to use a librairy to do this (or write your own parse, but it's not a good idea).

You can search more information about this one: Newtonsoft.json

Thi is a good library that allow you to parse json into object, and object into json.

[a link to Newtonsoft.Json](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json)